# Is it grocerycrud support for DB2?

Tags: php, codeigniter, db2, grocery-crud

i have question about grocercrud, does it really support for DB2?

because i had tried and it failed.

this is my connection setup (Codeigniter 3):

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'Driver={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER - DB2COPY1};Database=SAMPLE;hostname=localhost;port=50000;protocol=TCPIP;" . "boby.wayz; 1q2w3e4r5t;',
    'username' => 'boby.wayz',
    'password' => '1q2w3e4r5t',
    'database' => 'SAMPLE',
    'dbdriver' => 'odbc',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

and this the error that i've got:

> Error Number: S0002
>
> [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/NT64] SQL0204N "INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES" is an
>   undefined name. SQLSTATE=42704
>
> SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema =
>   'public'
>
> Filename:
>   C:/xampp/htdocs/personal/dailywork/system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 691

Answer (score 0):

The website says in [known issues](http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/known-issues) that it only supports MySQL with MySQLi.

DB2 provides a MySQL compatibility mode (but this requires that the database be created *after* MySQL compatibility mode is already enabled).  This would solve the initial problem you're seeing (a database created with MySQL compatibility mode will have the view `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`), but it's not clear whether that will truly solve the problem of getting Grocery CRUD to work with DB2.